# Using @time in Julia gives surprising results

Tags: performance, julia

I am not sure why this is happening.

```
using Formatting: printfmt


function within(x,y)
    if x * x + y * y <= 1 
        true 
    else 
        false 
    end
end

function π_estimation_error(estimated_value)
    pi_known = 3.1415926535897932384626433
    return abs((pi_known - estimated_value) / 100)    
end

function estimate_π_1(n)
    count = 0
    for i = 1:n
      if within(rand(), rand())
        count = count + 1
      end
    end    
    pi_est = count/n*4
    printfmt("n: {} π estimated {:.8f}, error {:.10f}", n, pi_est, π_estimation_error(pi_est))
end

function estimate_π_2(n)
    rand_coords = rand(n, 2) .^ 2
    count = sum(rand_coords[:,1] + rand_coords[:,2] .<= 1)
    pi_est = count/n*4
    printfmt("n: {} π estimated {:.8f}, error {:.10f}", n, pi_est, π_estimation_error(pi_est))
end

number_of_experiments = 20000000

for i = 1:10
    print("1 :: ")
    @time estimate_π_1(number_of_experiments)
    print("2 :: ")
    @time estimate_π_2(number_of_experiments)
end
```

What is the proper way to get consistent results? Not sure why this is happening. The allocation numbers seem way off.

```
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14188540, error 0.0000029275  0.507643 seconds (1.15 M allocations: 56.432 MiB, 8.75% gc time)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14141280, error 0.0000017985  0.786538 seconds (1.13 M allocations: 1.100 GiB, 13.17% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14118120, error 0.0000041145  0.054791 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14207560, error 0.0000048295  0.536932 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.11% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14119660, error 0.0000039605  0.054647 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14154040, error 0.0000005225  0.529361 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.04% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14188640, error 0.0000029375  0.054321 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14177120, error 0.0000017855  0.532848 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.01% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14191880, error 0.0000032615  0.055158 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14213220, error 0.0000053955  0.524499 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.02% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14161380, error 0.0000002115  0.054355 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14174220, error 0.0000014955  0.529431 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.17% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14178600, error 0.0000019335  0.054558 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14152500, error 0.0000006765  0.537786 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 13.89% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14163340, error 0.0000004075  0.055921 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14220380, error 0.0000061115  0.521758 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.19% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14092000, error 0.0000067265  0.054592 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14177460, error 0.0000018195  0.527376 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.10% gc time)
1 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14171780, error 0.0000012515  0.054904 seconds (181 allocations: 6.711 KiB)
2 :: n: 20000000 π estimated 3.14136040, error 0.0000023225  0.528569 seconds (196 allocations: 1.045 GiB, 14.04% gc time)
```

Is this happeing because some optimization kicks in?

Comment: "why **this** is happening", could you be specific about what you mean by "this"?

Comment: slicing, building a string, and printing

Comment: the first numbers are results of compilation, the rest are the runs on compiled code. the difference in times after that comes from the fact that your computer is not an ideal machine that only runs your code

Comment: The allocation numbers seem pretty reasonable to me. The first round is of course high, due to compilation, but after that they seem ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you are asking why the first run of a function is always much slower and allocates more memory than subsequent runs?

The reason is that Julia is compiled language - so the first time you run any function, Julia will compile it to binary code, creating binary methods corresponding to the most commonly expected input types. For any later calls of that function, Julia will see that it's already generated the binary code and just use that.

Comment: thanks! This is exactly what I was wondering about. I guess I can discard the results that are outside of a certain threshold (like 2 standard deviations from the middle for example).

Comment: The best approach is to use the `@btime` macro from the BenchmarkTools package, rather than `@time`. It will only measure actual execution time, and will repeat runs to get a stable average. Also useful if the function is really fast.